# I am having issues with my classes and methods code for my FLVS Class

Tags: python, class, methods

```
class Superhero:
    def __init__(self, name = "", specialability = "", adversary = "", impotence = ""):
         # Create a new superhero and give her characteristics.
        self.name = name
        self.specialability = specialability
        self.adversary = adversary
        self.impotence = impotence

def main():
    newSuperhero = Superhero("Memphis May", "Teleportation", "Mind     control", "Mathematics", "Homework")
    print("Allow me to introduce you to my superhero, her name is " + newSuperhero.name)
    print("She is extremely gifted and she was blessed with the following specialability's: " + newSuperhero.specialability)
    print("Yet, she constantly faces her greatest adversary, " +  newSuperhero.adversary)
    print("Unfortunately, her biggest impotence is " + newSuperhero.impotence)

main()
```

Comment: What are the issues you're having?

Comment: So what is the question ?

Comment: Please fix your formatting. The easiest thing to do is to copy-and-paste directly from your text editor, then highlight that text and press cltr-k

Comment: Your class doesn't have any methods (except `__init__()`).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Please look at the comment my teacher made @MelanieShebel

Comment: I added a new comment regarding my teachers criticism below @t.m.adams

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're having is too many arguments, what you want to do is make it Mathematics homework I believe.

Line ten `newSuperhero = Superhero("Memphis May", "Teleportation", "Mind     control", "Mathematics", "Homework")` you have which is what is causing your issue. Changing it to:

`newSuperhero = Superhero("Memphis May", "Teleportation", "Mind     control", "Mathematics homework.")` should resolve your issue.

Comment: My teacher said that I need to use functions outside main method and call the functions in the main method. According to her I am not doing it. I don't even know what her response means.